# Hacer que un DIV te siga mientras navegas, siendo FLEXBOX y dentro de otro DIV

Tags: html, css

Buenas tardes. Tengo tres principales `div`, un `parent` y dos `child`. El `parent` es un flexbox, por lo que sus hijos se ajustarán al ancho de la página. El problema es que quiero que uno solo de los dos hijos/`child` te siga mientras navegas.

Actualmente, la página web tiene esta visualización: [image: erth5rty]

El primer `div` es básicamente el que tiene todo el contenido, el de la izquierda. El segundo es el de la derecha, color rojo. Quisiera que este último te siguiera mientras *scroll*eas/navegas. Para esto puedo usar `position: fixed`.

Sin embargo, cuando activo esta posición el `div` rojo se sobrepone encima del azul. Lo que quiero es que se siga manteniendo a la derecha. ¿Cómo puedo realizar esto? ¿Usando `margin`?

Aquí tienen un [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alej27/ccaqfs8b/2/). El `div` izquierdo tiene `class = main` y el derecho `class = images` (este es el que tiene `position: fixed`, pueden eliminar esta propiedad para que vean cómo se ajusta pero no te sigue).

Comment: No entiendo qué es lo que no funciona, no veo en que punto se sobrepone al de la izquierda.

Comment: Estaba de acuerdo con @Shaz porque yo lo veía bien pero en chrome sí que falla el flexbox con posisión `fixed`.

Comment: Yo lo probé en chrome de hecho ;)

Comment: @Shaz tienes que cambiar el valor de la propiedad `position` a `fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto.

```
div.images {
width: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
background-color: red;
height: 100vh;
margin-left: 68%; <---- Solo inserta esto
position: fixed;
}
```

¿Es esto lo que deseas?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que dices no tiene mucho sentido por las siguientes razones:

- Al hacer la parte izquierda absoluta o fija, el cuerpo del padre **no crecerá**.
- Si haces la parte derecha fija entonces usar flexbox carece de sentido por que no aplicará si tiene `position: fixed`.

Lo que deseas puedes realizarlo de dos formas:

1. Dándole un posicion fixed al div de la derecha.
2. Dándole un alto del 100% del view height Y un `overflow: auto` al div del contenido.

Ambas resultarán en lo mismo, pero la segunda opción es más limpia.

**Marcado**

```
<section class="parent">
  <section class="child">
    <div class="content">A</div>
  </section>
  <section class="child">
    <div class="content">B</div>
  </section>
</section>
```

#### Opción #1

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.child:first-of-type {
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.child:last-of-type {
  background-color: teal;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 1.6%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
.content {
  background-color: coral;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 48pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
  height: 1500px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Vemos como al div derecho le hemos dado `right: 1.6%`. Esto es necesario de lo contrario, **tapará el scrollbar**. Puedes ponerlo a 0 y verlo por tú mismo.

#### Opción #2

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
}
.child:first-of-type {
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child:last-of-type {
  background-color: teal;
}
.content {
  background-color: coral;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 48pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
  height: 1500px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Esta solución es la más limpia. No necesitamos hacer uso de `position: fixed`. Tan solo el padre deberá tener el 100% del view height y el div izquierdo, igual, pero haciéndolo scrollable con `overflow: scroll`.

#### Demos

- [Opción 1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGKYXo)
- [Opción 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkgRKz)

Comment: _"Si haces la parte derecha fija entonces usar flexbox carece de sentido por que no aplicará si tiene position: fixed."_. Esto no es del todo cierto ya que el problema es en Chrome (quizá en webkit) pero en Firefox e IE funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con un

```
float: right;
```

Lo usas en el `div` que quieres que se mantenga a la derecha.